# How can I reuse the dataframe and use alternative for iloc to run an iterative imputer in Azure databricks

Tags: scala, azure-databricks, pyspark

I am running an iterative imputer in Jupyter Notebook to first mark the known incorrect values as "Nan" and then run the iterative imputer to impute the correct values to achieve required sharpness in the data. The sample code is given below:

```
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
import numpy as np
import pandas as p

idx =  [761, 762, 763, 764]
cols = ['11','12','13','14']

def fit_imputer():
    for i in range(len(idx)):
        for col in cols:
            dfClean.iloc[idx[i], col] = np.nan
            print('Index = {} Col = {} Defiled Value is: {}'.format(idx[i], col, dfClean.iloc[idx[i], col]))
            # Run Imputer for Individual row        
            tempOut = imp.fit_transform(dfClean)
            print("Imputed Value  = ",tempOut[idx[i],col] )
            dfClean.iloc[idx[i], col] = tempOut[idx[i],col]
            print("new dfClean Value = ",dfClean.iloc[idx[i], col])
            origVal.append(dfClean_Orig.iloc[idx[i], col])
```

I get an error when I try to run this code on Azure Databricks using pyspark or scala. Because the dataframes in spark are immutable also I cannot use iloc as I have used it in pandas dataframe.

Is there a way or better way of implementing such imputation in databricks?

Comment: Spark dataframes are unordered. You cannot access rows using their index, as you would do in pandas using `iloc`.

Comment: You can consider using the [Spark ML Imputer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.Imputer)